# Fedora - Battery indicator fails to display in top left panel

Tags: fedora, gnome, gnome3

The Battery indicator icon is not visible in the top panel.
I am running Fedora 30 with GNOME.
I tried restarting `upower` but it failed.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart upower

Job for upower.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status upower.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

```
$ systemctl status upower.service

● upower.service - Daemon for power management
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/upower.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-06-12 20:10:41 IST; 10s ago
     Docs: man:upowerd(8)
  Process: 11765 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/upowerd (code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE)
 Main PID: 11765 (code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE)

Jun 12 20:10:41 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: upower.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Jun 12 20:10:41 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: upower.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jun 12 20:10:41 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Daemon for power management.
Jun 12 20:10:41 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: upower.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 12 20:10:41 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: upower.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 12 20:10:41 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Daemon for power management.
Jun 12 20:10:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: upower.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 12 20:10:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: upower.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 12 20:10:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Daemon for power management.
```

**UPD1:**

```
journalctl -xe
```

```
-- Automatic restarting of the unit upower.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Jun 13 08:44:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Daemon for power management.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit upower.service has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- A stop job for unit upower.service has finished.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 4358 and the job result is done.
Jun 13 08:44:23 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=upower comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=suc>
Jun 13 08:44:23 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=upower comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=succ>
Jun 13 08:44:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Daemon for power management...
-- Subject: A start job for unit upower.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- A start job for unit upower.service has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 4358.
Jun 13 08:44:23 localhost.localdomain audit[6540]: AVC avc:  denied  { remount } for  pid=6540 comm="(upowerd)" scontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0 tclass=filesystem permissive=0
Jun 13 08:44:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[6540]: upower.service: Failed to set up mount namespacing: Permission denied
Jun 13 08:44:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[6540]: upower.service: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /usr/libexec/upowerd: Permission denied
-- Subject: Process /usr/libexec/upowerd could not be executed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- The process /usr/libexec/upowerd could not be executed and failed.
-- 
-- The error number returned by this process is ERRNO.
Jun 13 08:44:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: upower.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit upower.service has exited.
-- 
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 226.
Jun 13 08:44:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: upower.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- The unit upower.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 13 08:44:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Daemon for power management.
-- Subject: A start job for unit upower.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- A start job for unit upower.service has finished with a failure.
```

[image: Here is what the dropdown menu looks like]

Comment: Please run the `journalctl -xe` command as systemctl indicated and add the relevant output to your question.

Comment: Added @0xSheepdog

Comment: Also, not sure if it is related, the sudo prompt takes a longer time than usual to appear

Comment: Appears that a bug has already been reported https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1708991

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the issue described here. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1708991

Due to `snapd` and ``SELinux``` issues. Updating your system should fix it now.